# Dragging calendar events is slow in Fullcalendar Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

I've imported fullcalendar in my Rails project using the `gem 'fullcalendar-rails', '~> 2.3.1.0'`.

Whenever I drag events around on my calendar, there is significant "latency" i.e. the event UI element stutters around. The version on http://fullcalendar.io is significantly better.

Did anyone have the same problem and/or how do you fix it?

EDIT:

I neglected to include any implementation code because I couldn't get the calendar to work even with a vanilla implementation, so I thought it was an issue with the fullcalendar-rails. I've included my solution below (it happened to be the fault of designmodo's flat-ui stylesheet).

Comment: The problems you've encountered could be caused by any number of things. Is it reasonable to provide no code and no evidence of how you've implemented Full Calendar and still expect an answer? Did you at least open your browser's scripting console to see if there was anything weird going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I apologize for the nondescriptive question. I knew it was not anything in the code itself as I did try a vanilla implementation and the error still occurred.

I've finally pinpointed the problem to designmodo's Flat-UI gem. Their stylesheet adds a `-webkit-transition: 0.25s` and `transition: 0.25s` to `a` html tags, thus the `a` elements which happen to be the `.fc-event`s were affected by this.

I overrode this style by adding

```
a.fc-event {
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

into my custom CSS file.